# Padding a struct out to a precise size

Tags: c++, struct, padding

Consider the following `struct` definition:

```
#define SIZE ...  // it's a positive multiple of sizeof(Foo*)

struct Foo {
  Foo* ptr;
  char padding[SIZE - sizeof(Foo*)];
};
```

Given that `SIZE` is a positive multiple of the pointer size (`sizeof(Foo*)`), is it guaranteed by the standard that `sizeof(Foo) == SIZE`?

If it is not guaranteed, as a practical matter, are there any platforms in common use that provide a counter-example (where the equality doesn't hold)?

---

<sub>Yes, I'm aware of `alignas`...</sub>

Comment: I don't know of any ABIs where `Foo *` and `Foo` would have a different alignment

Comment: I'd post this as an answer, but the language lawyers would kill me for saying it.  **In practice**, what you have posted works, and many compilers will document their padding behavior as well.  But if you really want to make sure, there are pragmas on compilers to guarantee this.  Particularly, [__attribute__ ((packed))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) on gcc/g++ and [pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) attribute on Visual C++.

Comment: @selbie thanks! The thing about `packed` is the compilers where I know how to do it "packed" are the ones I already know do the sane thing here (i.e., they don't need packed anyways). It's the weird ones that matter, and since I know about them, I don't know how to pack...

Comment: Add a compile time assert: `bool cta[(sizeof(Foo) == SIZE) ? 1 : -1];` If your padding assumptions are broken, then it will force the compiler to not build the code.

Comment: Yup, I've done it with `static_assert`. Here I'm more trying to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee about padding.

> ```
> C++ Standard (working draft n4741) 6.7(4) Types
>
> 4 The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N 
> unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals 
> sizeof(T). The value representation of an object is the set of bits that 
> hold the value of type T. Bits in the object representation that are not 
> part of the value representation are padding bits. For trivially copyable 
> types, the value representation is a set of bits in the object 
> representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of 
> an implementation-deﬁned set of values. (41)
>
> (41) The intent is that the memory model of C++ is compatible with that 
> of ISO/IEC 9899 Programming Language C.
>
> C++ Standard (working draft n4741) 8.5.2.3(2) Sizeof
>
> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size 
> of the referenced type. When applied to a class, the result is the 
> number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required 
> for placing objects of that type in an array. The result of applying 
> sizeof to a potentially-overlapping subobject is the size of the type, 
> not the size of the subobject.78 When applied to an array, the result is 
> the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an 
> array of n elements is n times the size of an element.
> ```

I can point to no example, off-hand, where it would not hold, but based on the standard's memory model compatibility with "ISO/IEC 9899 Programming Language C", there can be no guarantees given regarding padding -- it is *implementation defined*.